# Mocking the IConfigurationSection using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, nsubstitute

I'm trying to mock the `IConfiguration` as well as the `IConfigurationSection` using `NSubstitute`. I have a custom configuration file that I use to configure HTTP clients on startup. The problem is when I try to mock, I cannot make it return my custom class `ClientConfiguration` using a `.Returns()`. I get this error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException: 'Can not return value of type ClientConfiguration for IDisposable.Dispose (expected type void)'

**Code:**

```
var configSection = Substitute.For<IConfigurationSection>();
var configuration = Substitute.For<IConfiguration>();

configSetion.Get<ClientConfiguration>().Returns(new ClientConfiguration());

configuration.GetSection(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(configSection);
```

Comment: Don't bother trying to mock that. A Configuration instance can be built with an in-memory provider to get the desired behavior. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/64795010/5233410

Comment: This worked for me after managing to generate a Json string from my custom class. Thanks!